# iPhone SDK - DidSelectRow Error

Tags: uitableview

I'm trying to find the error for hours now :/

This is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
if (self.CountryDetailViewController == nil) {
    CountryDetailViewController *aCountryDetail = [[CountryDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CountryDetailView" bundle:nil];
    self.CountryDetailViewController = aCountryDetail;
    [aCountryDetail release];
}

CountryDetailViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [CountryArray objectAtIndex:row]];

MyAppAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.CountryNavController pushViewController:CountryDetailViewController animated:YES];                                 
}
```

I get the following errors:

> Accessing unknown 'setTitle:' class method
>   Expected expression before CountryDetailViewController

I think you can see from the post what I'd like to do.
It's so simple, I guess, but I don't get a clue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CountryDetailViewController is most likely your class name. Probably changing the first character to lowercase will work. Assuming that the ivar is defined.